# Application gateway - 404 while invoking backend service (Linux app service)

Tags: linux, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I have a problem with configuring the Application gateway.
I have 2 app services that are hosted on Linux.

- Frontend
- Backend

I would like to configure the next behavior:

When the user types in URL ->  mysite.com - redirect to the Frontend

When the user types in URL ->  mysite.com/api - redirect to the Backend

My configured Rules

[image]

On Windows app services we have "Virtual applications and directories" that can fix this
an issue like this:
[image: imege]

But the Linux app service does not have this option.
[image]

I have tried to update my settings and update '/' to 'override backend path' but this does not help me.
If everyone has any suggestions, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results*

I have created the application gateway and configured the Linux web app

[image]

Created the frontend, backend pool settings and configured the virtual machine and app service to backend pool

When I check I got the same mapping path I am not able to see the mapping path

[image]

I am not able to get the virtual applications and directories path because this option is not available for Linux app service

We can create the virtual directory fields by adding manually if we need

> For creating the field manually I have followed this [Documentation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/71066523-3ead-4b77-93e1-2d417004a8a9/how-to-set-virtual-applications-and-directories-for-linux-based-web-app?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

I have used the .htaccess to rewrite and create the new virtual level application and directories
After setting all the properties I am able to get the virtual machine and directory fields

[image]